# Compile AppEngine project that has datastore callbacks with Ant

Tags: google-app-engine, ant, google-cloud-datastore, annotation-processing

I've implemented [datastore callbacks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/callbacks) in our AppEngine project and set it up in Eclipse as indicated in the link.

Now I'm having trouble getting it to compile in Ant. Here's what I have for the javac target now:

```
<path id="appengine.api.path">
    <pathelement location="${appengine.folder}/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar" />
</path>

<target name="javac" depends="clean,libs" description="Compile java source">
    <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <apt compile="false" preprocessdir=".apt_build_generated" destdir="war/WEB-INF/classes"
        srcdir="src"
        factorypathref="appengine.api.path"
        >
    </apt>
    <javac srcdir="src" includes="**" encoding="utf-8" destdir="war/WEB-INF/classes" source="1.6" target="1.6" nowarn="true" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
        <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
    </javac>
    <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/classes">
        <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.java" />
    </copy>

</target>
```

The apt task runs but all it does is list a bunch of annotations that don't have processor, including the PrePut annotation.

I've tried setting factorypathref to the ${appengine.folder}/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar but then it says the appengine-api.jar reference is not found (I've verified the path exists). I've also looked through the jar file to see if I can find the class it uses as the factory but haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally discovered the problem. We were using the Eclipse compiler in our Ant build for other reasons. When we switched back to the built-in Java compiler, the annotation processor started working fine.